# Python 3.7 iteration

Tags: python, iteration

Given an integer `n`, the function `legendre_n` should return the number of prime numbers between `n^2` and `(n+1)^2`.

My code is as such:

```
def is_prime(n):
   if n ==1:
      return False
   elif n ==2:
      return True
   elif n>2 :
      for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i ==0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
def legendre_n(n):
  counter = 0
  for i in range (n**2,(n+1)**2):
      if is_prime(i):
          counter = counter + 1
      else:
          counter+=0
   return counter
        
print(legendre_n(1))  ==2
print(legendre_n(2))  ==2
print(legendre_n(3))  ==2
print(legendre_n(12)) ==5
```

I'm supposed to get the above answers but instead I get 2 ,2 ,4, 12
Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried printing `i` each time `counter` is incremented? Which numbers does it count that it should not count?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `is_prime` method. You are returning `False` in the `else` block in the `for` loop which is not correct.

It should be as:

```
def is_prime(n):
   if n == 1:
      return False
   elif n == 2:
      return True
   elif n > 2:
      for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
      return True
```

Comment: So, does it mean that if n is a prime number more than 2, it will keep running the (if n%1 ==0) line from 2 until it reaches (n-1), thus keep returning None ,then exits the loop(which then executes (return True)?

Comment: yes, you are right, you could also reduce the range to `sqrt(n)` for further optimization

Comment: But if n is not prime, it will return False from the for loop, but it will still execute return True? Won't it become True then?

Comment: with `return` statement, the method is returned from that line and no further statements are executed thereafter.

Comment: Ah ok, that clears things up. Thanks for being so clear in your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your is_prime() function is flawed.

Here's a simpler one you can use:

```
def isPrime(n):
    return (n==2) if n<3 else n%2 and all(n%f for f in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2))

     #     0,1,2     ...      odd and not divisible by any odd factor up to √n
```